# First component built, need help adding joomla category functionality

Tags: components, joomla1.5

I have created the beginnings of a product entry component that will allow a user to edit an existing product or enter a new one through the administrator section. The next step I would like to take (and need guidance on) is how to categorize the products. So I would have something similar to this:

Motherboards - Pentium - Xeon - AMD

Hard Drives - SATA - USB

Basic examples, but I hope it gets the point across. I see where Joomla has a categories component, but have not been able to find a good tutorial on how I might hook into it. I would like to create categories for the products like I would with articles and then assign individual products into those categories.

Any guidance you could give me would be appreciated, and feel free to ask any questions if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually good tutorials right on http://docs.joomla.org.
http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_categories

It you are a beginner you really should review the whole tutorial or you might want to get the Joomla! Programming book.

Comment: Thanks for the response Elin. Unfortunately I am programming for 1.5 and for whatever reason the documentation does not seem to be as complete for it as for 2.5. I have actually found examples to get this to work in 2.5 but nothing for 1.5.